# Ocultar inputs al seleccionar

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo este html que itera inputs dependiendo de la información de mi tabla

```
               <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 m-form__group-sub">
                            <?php 
                             $lista=$listaAreas->getlistAssignmentAreas(2);
                            foreach ($lista as $key => $value){
                                $idAsignaturas=$value->idAsignaturas;
                                $nombreAsignaturas=utf8_encode
                        ($value->getNombreAsignaturas());

                           $idAreaAcademica=$value->getIdAreaAcademica(); ?>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label
                                    class="m-checkbox m-checkbox--solid m-checkbox--success position-static">
                                    <input id="areaCultural" class="areaCultural" type="checkbox"
                                    value="<?php echo($idAsignaturas)  ?>" >
                                    &nbsp;<b><?php echo "$nombreAsignaturas";?></b>

                                    <?php 
                                    $lista=$listaAreas->getlistAssignmentTema($idAsignaturas);
                                    foreach ($lista as $key => $value){
                                        $idTema=$value->idTema;
                                        $nombreTema=utf8_encode($value->nombreTema);
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label
                                            class="m-checkbox m-checkbox--solid m-checkbox--success position-static">
                                            <input  type="radio" name="temacultural" id="temacultural" 
                                            value="<?php echo($idTema) ?>">
                                            &nbsp;<?php echo "$nombreTema"?>
                                            <span></span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                <?php }//TERMINA SEGUNDO FOREACH?>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                                    <?php }//TERMINA PRIMER FOREACH
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

lo itera de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que si el input principal que es `areaCultural`,  no se ha seleccionado no se vean los segundos input `temacultural`, coloqué una función pero lo que hace es que si selecciono un input principal se visualizan todos los demás y eso no es lo que quiero, si no que si selecciono uno solo se vean los input secundarios que corresponden a este.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias hacer algo asi:

```js
$("#selectTodo").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".pintura").each(function() {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        });
    }
    else {
        $(".pintura").each(function() {
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectTodo">Pintura<br>
Basico
<input type="checkbox" class="pintura"><br>
Intermedio
<input type="checkbox" class="pintura"><br>
Avanzado
<input type="checkbox" class="pintura"><br>
```

Si te fijas mediante el  id del checkbox verifico que este seleccionado, en caso de estarlo recorro uno a uno los checkbox pertenecientes a este mediante su clase "pintura" y los coloco como checked(seleccionados), esto lo hago con Jquery de la misma forma seria para Musica y los que desees.

Espero te ayude..!!

Comment: no , es que eso no es lo que busco , si no que al seleccionar un checkbox me aparezcan sus check box correspondientes

Comment: es decir si selecciono Pintura muestre Basico, Intermedio, Avanzado...?? osea que por defecto aparezcan ocultos los checkbox ?

Comment: que aprezcan los check box pintura y demas los principales, y que solo al ser selccionado el principal aparezca los corespondientes a ese